# Python: insertar lista aleatoria en otra función

Tags: python

antes que nada pido perdon si esta pregunta suena muy tonta, pero soy nuevo en Python.
Tengo la siguiente función que me genera una lista de 15 números aleatorios del 1 al 100.

```
import numpy as np
def numeroaleatorio():
    lista=[0]*15
    for i in range(15):
        lista[i]=np.random.randint(1,100)
    return lista
```

El problema me viene para en la siguiente función utilizar esta lista generada anteriormente de forma aleatoria, no encuentro forma de utilizar la lista anterior para nuevas funciones como esta de dividir los números de la lista entre 7 por ejemplo. Lo unico que consigo es dividir una nueva lista aleatoria.

```
def Dividirlista(lista1,divisor):
    Auxiliar=[]
    for i in range(15):
        Auxiliar.append(lista1[i]/divisor)
    return Auxiliar

Arreglo=numeroaleatorio()
print(Arreglo)
Dividirlista(Arreglo,7)
```

¡Un saludo!

Comment: Se te permite hacer algo como lista[:7] y lista[7:]?

Comment: Buen día, no entiendo muy bien el problema que tienes, el código que pusiste funciona tal como lo describes. La primera función genera una lista y la segunda función realiza operaciones en la misma lista. ¿Sería posible que has resuelto el problema al crear la pregunta?

Comment: Es verdad, es como decias, gracias. Tenia la duda porque primero intentaba generar la lista de la primera parte y despues generaba la segunda parte en vez de generar directamente solo la segunda parte. Mil gracias!